# Vocabulary app for Dutch

Tags: resource-request, vocabulary, electronic-resources, dutch

I am looking for a mobile app or website that I can create personal vocabulary list for a Dutch. Among my searches in Google Play, I see several apps for language learning, but didn't find a good app for vocabulary learning. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

- **[Anki](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki)** is a flashcards app that many people use to learn languages. You can create your own flashcards with words or sentences, or download existing decks.
- **[Tatoeki](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tatoeki)** is an app to browse sentences in many languages and search for sentences containing a specific word. Some sentences have recorded audio. You can create flashcards from any sentence.

Answer (score -1):

clozemaster and drops are also very good, adding to what @Thomas said